# Open file:///path/index.html from localhost

Tags: php, html, apache

Any idea how to browse file:///C:/Results/index.html from localhost using a href?

i created the test html file (C:/ser/xampp/htdocs/filter/file.html) and place the link to local page (C:/Results/index.html) and i tired to open that link from (`http://localhost/filter/file.html`) it didn't work. But when i tired to open link from (file:///C:/ser/xampp/htdocs/filter/file.html) it worked.

I hope this make sense.

I googled it but didn't find any useful solution. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does the XAMPP maps `localhost` to your folder ? i.e. what is the `DocumentRoot` of the Apache ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor its '/ser/xampp/htdocs' but it didn't work for file:///C:/ser/xampp/htdocs/filter/file.html also

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` .Just paste code:`127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost`.Then restart xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path is given like as below and if you access from localhost, it will make a search for a file which is inside htdocs folder

```
<a href="file:///C:/Results/index.html">Click Here</a>
```

To access the C:/Results folder, create a VirtualHost for the C:/Results and give that respective ip to the href like below. So that you can access the file from localhost.

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.4:1003/index.html">Click Here</a>
```

To create VirtualHost,
* Open /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and enter the below lines. Dont delete other lines

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.4:1003>
DocumentRoot "file:///C:/Results"
</VirtualHost>
```

* Open /etc/apache2/ports.conf and enter the below lines. Dont delete other lines

```
Listen 1003
```

* Restart apache.